# What should pwd be replaced with?

Tags: linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the page

http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages

```
$ ln -s `pwd`/image_common/image_transport/tutorial/ ./src/image_transport_tutorial
```

command appears. Here 'pwd' should be replaced with something else. What could it be?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228555/what-should-pwd-be-replaced-with?/) by [jbpark03](https://answers.ros.org/users/26212/jbpark03/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think you need to replace `pwd` in the command you referred to. On Ubuntu (and other Linux I assume), surrounded by buckquote "`" symbol, the output of command is filled in.

So if you follow the tutorial line-by-line, you should be at `~/image_transport_ws/`, which `pwd` command will return and that's what the tutorial you linked to expects.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4